# Gluster + ZFS, deadlock during benchmarking: zfs_iput_taskq 100% cpu

Tags: centos, storage, nfs, zfs, glusterfs

First some background:
I work at a company that runs a PHP-webapplication. We have a storage backend mounted over NFS on several webservers. Today we have the issue if one webserver writes a file over NFS, sometimes the file does not appear at other mounted clients until a few minutes later. It is also not redundant so we cannot perform any "invisible" maintenance.

I've been looking at migrating to a GlusterFS solution (two or three replicated bricks/machines for redundancy). Now, using XFS as the storage filesystem "behind" Gluster works very well, performance wise. Gluster also does not seem to have the sync problem mentioned above.

However, I would like to use ZFS as the backend filesystem, the reasons being;

- Cheap compression (currently storing 1.5TB uncompressed)
- Very easy to expand the storage-volume "live" (one command, compared
  the LVM mess)
- Snapshotting, bit-rot protection and all the other ZFS glory.

In my demo-setup of the solution I have three servers with Replicated Gluster with a ZFS backend pool at a separate disk on each server. I'm using CentOS 6.5 with ZFS on Linux (0.6.2) + GlusterFS 3.4. I have also tried with Ubuntu 13.10. Everything is in VMware ESX.

To test this setup I have mounted the volume over Gluster, and then running BlogBench (http://www.pureftpd.org/project/blogbench) to simulate load. The issue I'm having is that at the end of the test, the ZFS storage seems to get stuck in a deadlock. All three machines have "zfs_iput_taskq" running at 90-100% CPU, and the test freezes. If I abort the test, the deadlock does not go away, only option seems to be hard reboot.

I have tried:

- Disabled atime
- Disabled scheduler (noop)
- Different compression/no compression
- Blogbench directly on ZFS works fine
- Blogbench on Gluster + XFS as backend works fine

Ideas? Should I just drop ZFS and go with something else? alternatives?

Regards Oscar

Comment: How much RAM do you have on the ZFS nodes? Also, how many disks per node? Are you using zvols at all?

Comment: 3GB per node, one disk - since it is a labb-environment, each nodes ZFS-disk is only 5GB (so ram is supposedly enough). Should I try to crank up the ram anyways?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ZFS on Linux needs a bit of basic tuning in order to operate well under load. There's a bit of a struggle between the ZFS ARC and the Linux virtual memory subsystem.

For your CentOS systems, try the following:

Create an `/etc/modprobe.d/zfs.conf` configuration file. This is read during the module load/boot.

Add something like:

```
options zfs zfs_arc_max=40000000000
options zfs zfs_vdev_max_pending=24
```

Where zfs_arc_max is roughly 40% of your RAM in bytes (*Edit: try* `zfs_arc_max=1200000000`). The compiled-in default for zfs_vdev_max_pending is 8 or 10, depending on version. The value should be high (48) for SSD or low-latency drives. Maybe 12-24 for SAS. Otherwise, leave at default.

You'll want to also have some floor values in `/etc/sysctl.conf`

```
vm.swappiness = 10
vm.min_free_kbytes = 512000
```

Finally, with CentOS, you may want to install `tuned` and `tuned-utils` and set your profile to virtual-guest with `tuned-adm profile virtual-guest`.

Try these and see if the problem persists.

**Edit:**

Run `zfs set xattr=sa storage`. [Here's why.](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues/457) You may have to wipe the volumes and start again (*I'd definitely recommend doing so*).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input, I have performed the changes you suggested and I'm running blogbench again, will post results.

Comment: Unfortunately, the issue remains. Strangely enough only one node got locked up this time.. still caused the cluster to be deadlocked though. Also increased ram to 4gb per node.

Comment: @MannerMan I'd need stack trace or `dmesg` output when this happens, then.

Comment: I reset everything, started the test again whilst keeping an eye on dmesg (watch -n 0.2 "dmesg | tail -n 10"). All nodes got deadlocked after a while, *nothing* appeared in dmesg or syslog. However - the deadlock did get released when I aborted, so something has made a difference. How does one get a stacktrace from kernel/zfs?

Comment: This may not be a ZFS problem. But please post the output of `zpool get all`, `zpool status -v`, `zfs get all` and `zfs list`

Comment: It's all here; http://pastebin.com/M1QB1uiX

EDIT: This is the current "top"-output from the three nodes, during deadlock, http://i.imgur.com/fWLwNhT.png

Comment: @MannerMan How many vCPUs have you allocated to each "node"?

Comment: @MannerMan See my edit. Good luck.

Comment: I will make a new pool and try xattr! (2 vCPU's btw), might not be able to test before the weekend but i'll post results on Monday otherwise.

Comment: And indeed after a zpool re-creation and, *zfs set xattr=sa storage* it works flawless, no more zfs_iput_taskq! Thanks a bunch @ewwhite, I salute you Sir.

Comment: @MannerMan Excellent.